# Silverlight Threadpool

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, threadpool

I have a question about threading in Silverlight.  I come mainly from a winForms background and usually use the following wrapper class to do my threading: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163644.aspx

It has worked for doing window development but I am not able to use it in Silverlight.  The reason is because ExecutionContext is marked with the [SecurityCritical] attribute making it impossible to call from Silverlight.

Is there a similar wrapper class out there for Silverlight or is there a way I can get around this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the class you cited even in a WinForm application. It still uses `Thread.Abort` which can (and probably would) corrupt the app domain. Instead, use the new [Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) mechanisms in the Task Parallel Library. You will have to rethink your whole approach to cancelling the work items though. This is because you can no longer rely on forced termination and have to use cooperative termination instead. The advantage is that the later can be guaranteed to avoid corrupting the app domain.

Comment: Didn't know about the new Cancellation mechanisms.  I'll have to take a look.

Comment: This will help with the cancellation of a thread, but how do i deal with the ExecutionContext issue?

Comment: @Toad: Is there any reason you were using it other than because it was part of the wrapper class you cited? If not then my advice is to stop using it.

Comment: That is what I want to do....what could I use in the place of ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, delegate { item.Callback(item.State); }, null);

Comment: @Toad: That is the code inside `AbortableThreadPool.HandleItem` though. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. **Stop using `AbortableThreadPool` completely. Don't use anything from that MSDN article. Pretend like it was never written.** Instead, use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or the like to get a work item executing asynchronously. Then use the TPL cancellation mechanisms to stop it if necessary.

Comment: Much clearer now.  I'll start looking into what you recommended.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at cancellation tokens (via the CancellationTokenSource) available only in SL5. It uses a similar mechanism as the one used in your MSDN mag ref.

This is a [good 'how-to' article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx). Some [MSDN References here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), as well as [a lengthy but great article here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx)

All the best, and welcome to XAML programming :) You won't look back!

Comment: This will help with the cancellation of a thread, but how do i deal with the ExecutionContext issue?

Comment: see above, Brian's comment sums it up perfectly - TPL will not require ExecutionContext.

_It does not occur in unsafe thread pool operations (such as the UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem method), which do not transfer the compressed stack. Wherever the compressed stack flows, the managed principal, synchronization, locale, and user context also flow._ From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite existed code for using a "Task" ([Task Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609)) or a BackgroundWorker ([BackgroundWorker Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)).

We should use a newest technologies, which give us a technological evolution.